# Intellij IDEA debug error with gradle multiply subproject in the same package name

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Recently I encountered a annoying error with intellij idea.

I'm working on multiply subprojects in the same package name, but when I used debug on the code, it always opened the file with the same name in the other subproject and told me that the class file is wrong.

Have any idea on it? How can I avoid this problems? Thanks.

Below is `idea.log` when it happen.

[google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x83j4Lj7I3Dn5EzhE82MEKBjx6WO8KGJ/view?usp=sharing)

or something maybe important:

```
2020-11-16 21:19:34,546 [  12457]   INFO - s.kotlin.idea.scripting.gradle - [KOTLIN_GRADLE_DSL] script definitions aren't loaded yet. They should be loaded by invoking GradleScriptDefinitionsContributor.reloadIfNeeded from KotlinDslSyncListener: workingDir=C:/Users/QAQdd/Projects/Java/LCiJ gradleHome=C:/Users/QAQdd/Development/Scoop/apps/gradle/current 
2020-11-16 21:19:34,763 [  12674]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed (trace_hash = 1906654456) 
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerComponent.synchronizeRoots(ProjectRootManagerComponent.java:306)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerComponent.fireRootsChangedEvent(ProjectRootManagerComponent.java:210)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.fireRootsChanged(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:428)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.access$200(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl$BatchSession.rootsChanged(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:96)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.makeRootsChange(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:371)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.core.script.ucache.ScriptClassRootsUpdater$notifyRootsChanged$doNotifyRootsChanged$1$1.invoke(ScriptClassRootsUpdater.kt:231)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.core.script.ucache.ScriptClassRootsUpdater$notifyRootsChanged$doNotifyRootsChanged$1$1.invoke(ScriptClassRootsUpdater.kt:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.util.application.ApplicationUtilsKt$sam$com_intellij_openapi_util_Computable$0.compute(ApplicationUtils.kt)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$runWriteAction$16(ApplicationImpl.java:989)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteActionWithClass(ApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:989)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.util.application.ApplicationUtilsKt.runWriteAction(ApplicationUtils.kt:30)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.core.script.ucache.ScriptClassRootsUpdater$notifyRootsChanged$doNotifyRootsChanged$1.run(ScriptClassRootsUpdater.kt:226)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:201)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:802)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeLaterOnWriteThread$11(ApplicationImpl.java:791)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:132)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:47)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:188)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:971)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:841)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:744)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:451)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:802)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:499)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE.

Comment: @y.bedrov Thanks for your reply. I add the log file with google drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstall it...

Seems that I had pressed something when it showed 'alternative source available for the class' and the IDEA just choose that file as default. But the problem is I can't find somewhere to change that position... So... reinstall works find though stupid.